# Progress bar increment

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I want my progress bar to increase each time by 1 with maximum value 5 with same button click here is my code in button click

```
        ProgressBarQuestion.setMax(5);
        ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(1);
        int progress = ProgressBarQuestion.getProgress();
        Log.e("PROGRESS", String.valueOf(progress));
        ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(progress++);
```

but the problem is it increase by 1 on first click then its stop increasing.

Comment: You're resetting the progress on each click because of the `setProgress(1)` call. You'll need to move that somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the initialization somewhere else **ONCE**

```
ProgressBarQuestion.setMax(5);
ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(1);
```

Each time you click, you reset the progress back to 1 so it doesn't go up

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't calling `ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(1);`everytime?

Comment: Yes I am calling it every time .

Comment: dont call it everytime please !!  u r resetting it to 1

Comment: @PrithbirajChakraborty Then, you are resetting the counter to 1 everytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize your counter outside the function. A static integer should be incremented and passed onto your current calling function.

only use this in your function!!

```
ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(progress++);
```

and set progress outside your function

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your progress bar and set max at out side of button click

```
ProgressBarQuestion.setMax(5);
ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(1);
```

And only `setProgress` on button click as below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {               
    int progress = ProgressBarQuestion.getProgress();
    Log.e("PROGRESS", String.valueOf(progress));
    ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(progress++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//declare global
int count = 0;
 ProgressBarQuestion.setMax(5);
 ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(0);
//in on click

onClick(){
if(count<5){
  count++;
  ProgressBarQuestion.setProgress(count);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the progressBar to 1 and then incrementing it by 1 every time so on the first click it would increment to 2 and then every time it would set it to 1 and then increment it to 2.
So just shift setProgess function line to somewhere else.