# How can i fill horizontal progressBar with my data?

Tags: android, kotlin

I making lens tracker app.

I want to make progressBar to visualise progress of wearing.

For example my lenses have replacement period 14 days and i'm wearing it 3 days. So i want progressBar to take data of this variables, fill it with 14 and mark 14-3 = 11 days.

So we have something like |///////////---|

Comment: The answers to this question should answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801528/progress-bar-increment

Comment: @Shagufta thank you! Looks like it will help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try progressBar.setProgress(value you want to set) ;?

Comment: i didn't tried anything with it yet :) I just thought better ask people who worked with it than try it for my self and make another bad code :D